# How to count element frequency for a list

Tags: python, list, hash

I have a list of lists with 3-grams.  The sample input list is like this:

> A = [ ['the','big','bang'],['big','bang','theory'],...,['the','big','bang']

How do I count the frequency(number of number of occurrences) of these lists? Python complains list is not hashable.

For current case, I wish to get

```
dict[['the','big','bang'] = 2
dict[['big','bang','theory']] = 1
```

Thanks,

Comment: By frequency do you mean number of occurrences?

Comment: Yes, clarification of what you mean by frequency please. Example output would also be helpful.

Comment: Does the order of the list matter? Would all three of these count as occurances?

Comment: show your code. And what would be the expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lists are not hashable, that's why you cannot put them as keys of a dictionary. Convert the inner lists to tuples so that you can do the counting with a dict; or even better, use a `Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter
A = [['the','big','bang'],['big','bang','theory'],['the','big','bang']]
cnt = Counter(map(tuple, A))
for k, v in cnt.iteritems():
    print list(k), v
```

Output:

```
['big', 'bang', 'theory'] 1
['the', 'big', 'bang'] 2
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I am sorry for all the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

If your inner lists could be tuples, eg:

```
A = [('the', 'big', 'bang'), ('big', 'bang', 'theory'), ('the', 'big', 'bang')]
```

You can do:

```
result = {a:A.count(a) for a in set(A)} # dict comprehension
print result
{('big', 'bang', 'theory'): 1, ('the', 'big', 'bang'): 2}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in one line with a dictionary comprehension:

```
data = {i: A.count(list(i)) for i in set([tuple(j) for j in A])}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# order of individual lists matters
A = [ ['the','big','bang'],['big','bang','theory'],['the','big','bang']]
x = {}
for val in A:
    #val.sort() uncomment this if order within sublists does not matter
    x[str(val)] = x.setdefault(str(val), 0) + 1
print x
```